# HTML5 canvas saving

Tags: html5-canvas

```
 I have an html5 canvas and one image object to save this canvas   contents
```

(all drawings: images,draws,..).
     i want to play with the order (zindex) of these 2 objects from 1 button as below:
     when i want to draw, i call the canvas to the top .
     when i want to save i call image  to the top(full with datURL). (and rightclick to save as PNG)
    These switching operations must be repetitive and reliable.

I used this code (in a function called by the button onclick) but it fails in the second time (canvas have new contents)!

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('ycanvas1');
   // save canvas image as data url (png format by default)
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  // set canvasImg image src to dataURL - it can be saved as an image
 document.getElementById('canvasImg').src = dataURL;
```

NB: i use IE olecontrol embed on a form (working on local) .Is there any security  restrictions ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess in the first case:

```
    canvas.style.display="none"  // hide the canvas
    img.style.display=""              //show the image
```

in the second case:

```
    canvas.style.display=""        //show the canvas
    img.style.display="none"      //hide the image
```